# basic exception practice issue

Tags: exception, netbeans, try-catch

Uploaded screenshot of errors

This is an example to show a basic ArithmeticException is giving me error in netbeans. Any ideas.

[image: This is the screen shot of the errors]

```
public class Exception {

    public static void main (String[] args){ 

       try
       {            
            double x = 0;
            double y = 19000;
            double z;       

            double practice()
            {
                 double z = 4000;
                 return y - z;
            }

          public double practiceAgain()
          {
               double f = (9 + z);
               return f/x;         
          }
       }
         catch (ArithmeticExecption t){
         System.out.println(t);
       }
    }
```

Comment: It's usually helpful to provide the error you're getting...

Comment: "try" without "catch"" finally" or resource declarations   and ";" expected on double practice()

Comment: Please put the complete error messages into your question.  Keep them distinct.  What you provided in the comment above suggests your code has a missing `;` and/or a misplaced `}`.

Comment: Uploaded a screen shot... sorry about that

Comment: For the next time: 1) Please copy/paste the error message here instead of just a screenshot. 2) The posted code does not match the one in your screenshot and produces a different error. Please be consistent or post both error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states:

> Uncompilable source code – illegal start of expression at Exception:main(Exception.java:13)

Your source code is invalid out of multiple reasons:

1. Inside a method there is no such thing as a scope (i.e. `public`, `protected`, or `private`) – this is mentioned in your error message: line 13 in your `main` method.
2. Inside a method you cannot declare another method like this (i.e. on lines 18 and 24)

You have basically two ways to make the posted code compilable:

Either move the contents out of the `main` method:

```
public class Exception {
    double x = 0;
    double y = 19000;
    double z;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            practice();
            practiceAgain();
        } catch (ArithmeticExecption t){
             t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    double practice() {
        z = 4000;
        return y - z;
    }

    public double practiceAgain() {
        double f = (9 + z);
        return f/x;         
    }
}
```

Or do your processing directly in the `main` method:

```
public class Exception {
    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        try {
            double x = 0;
            double y = 19000;
            double z = 4000;
            double practice = y - z;
            double f = (9 + z);
            double practiceAgain = f/x;
        } catch (ArithmeticExecption t){
             t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Carsten... appreciate the help... new here.